# Looking for a custom swing JComponent object inside a standard Swing app using AssertJ FrameFixture

Tags: java, assertj

AssertJ has options for finding JPanel, JFrame, and suite of other standard Swing components, but I am wanting to test a custom Prefuse Display window derived directly from the JComponent class. What method on the main FrameFixture object should I use and what parameters should I use?

My best guess was:

```
window.panel(new GenericTypeMatcher<JComponent>(RadialDisplayWork.class) {
            @Override
            protected boolean isMatching(JComponent panel) {
                return "RadialDisplayWork".equals(panel.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        });
```

it isn't found and throws an exception as it should as WorkWindow is not a panel.